# jhipster seperate services during development

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, jhipster, jhipster-registry

#### Goal

We would like to create a development environment where we can run the latest versions of our registry, uaa and gateway on a server. We would then like to develop and run (in or outside docker) a microservice locally. This microservice should then be configured to connect and communicate to the other server.

#### Test setup

I have now generated a docker-compose via the jhipster sub-generator for our gateway, uaa and registry. I then tried to start the microservice i'm currently working on via gradlew, build it via gradlew dockerBuild and start the app.yml. I also tried to change the hostname in app.yml to localhost, 127.0.0.1 and the IP of the registries docker container.

#### My results

- If hostname is jhipster-registry: unknownhostexception. Most likely because the applications are started in different docker-compose files.
- If hostname is localhost or 127.0.0.1: http://127.0.0.1:8761/config/application/prod/master connection refused. Changing to  Perhaps some more configuration is required?
- If the hostname is the ip of the registry docker container: After the jhipster logo in the terminal no other output is given. But the application never stops due to an exception.

#### Files

docker-compose.yml (registry, uaa & gateway)

```
version: '2'
services:
    mygateway-app:
        image: mygateway
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://mygateway-mysql:3306/mygateway?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30
            - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=admin
        ports:
            - 8080:8080
        depends_on:
            - "mygateway-mysql"
            - "myuaa-app"
    mygateway-mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.20
        environment:
            - MYSQL_USER=root
            - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=mygateway
        command:             mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1 --skip-ssl
            --character_set_server=utf8mb4 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

    myuaa-app:
        image: myuaa
        environment:
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/eureka
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@jhipster-registry:8761/config
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://myuaa-mysql:3306/myuaa?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=30
            - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=admin
        depends_on:
            - "myuaa-mysql"
            - "jhipster-registry"
    myuaa-mysql:
        image: mysql:5.7.20
        environment:
            - MYSQL_USER=root
            - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD=yes
            - MYSQL_DATABASE=myuaa
        command:             mysqld --lower_case_table_names=1 --skip-ssl
            --character_set_server=utf8mb4 --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp

    jhipster-registry:
        extends:
            file: jhipster-registry.yml
            service: jhipster-registry
```

app.yml (microservice)

```
version: '2'
services:
    myservice-app:
        image: myservice
        environment:
            # - _JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xmx512m -Xms256m
            - SPRING_PROFILES_ACTIVE=prod,swagger
            - EUREKA_CLIENT_SERVICE_URL_DEFAULTZONE=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/eureka
            - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_URI=http://admin:$${jhipster.registry.password}@localhost:8761/config
            - SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://myservice-mysql:3306/myservice?useUnicode=true&characterEncoding=utf8&useSSL=false
            - JHIPSTER_SLEEP=10 # gives time for the JHipster Registry to boot before the application
            - JHIPSTER_REGISTRY_PASSWORD=admin
    myservice-mysql:
        extends:
            file: mysql.yml
            service: myservice-mysql
    # jhipster-registry:
    #     extends:
    #         file: jhipster-registry.yml
    #         service: jhipster-registry
    #     environment:
    #         - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_TYPE=native
    #         - SPRING_CLOUD_CONFIG_SERVER_COMPOSITE_0_SEARCH_LOCATIONS=file:./central-config/docker-config/
```